# How to install nest in Python3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, nest-simulator

After following the [Ubuntu/Debian installation instructions](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/linux_install.html) for the Nest simulator I can only import the nest module in python2.x, not python3.x

```sh
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:12:48) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/nest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nest/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import ll_api      # noqa
  File "/nest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nest/ll_api.py", line 72, in <module>
    from . import pynestkernel as kernel      # noqa
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_pynestkernel)
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are right. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default install compiles with the default Python version which is still 2 in Ubuntu.
To use Python 3, run:

```
cmake -Dwith-python=3 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=</install/path> </path/to/NEST/src>
```

Mentioned [here](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/install_options.html?highlight=Dwith#python3-binding-pynest) in the doc.

NB: don't forget to clear the build folder to avoid issues